# Using table in Latex. text overwitten

Tags: tables, workflow

[image]

I'm using this code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
throughout the evening. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

From directly [This Link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) but its causing the flow of table to shadow text of other side of the page. How to make sure that it takes full width of page and make sure no text hide or flows it.

Comment: you just need to make it less wide. for example can you not use abbreviated days `Wed.` not `Wednesday` so first column is less wide and of course you can change `p{5cm}` in the last column to `p{2cm}` or whatever works

Comment: yes that's why i i tried to make it 15 and it stretches but still text are below it.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by 15? it needs to be _less_ that 5 not more??? also the 2nd and 3rd columns are all wasted white space, use smaller heading such as min and max

Comment: I want to stretch it out to full page width and use that parts of page to show the table and text to go below it.  HTML <img> tag i thing cause text to go below directly i think ,

Comment: use a `table*` environment in that case so it floats to the top of the page.

Comment: Oh . i don't know what is environment but did added \begin{table*} and ended it too and that worked like a charm, Thank you. Just took birth in world of latex, Thank ya